# Not able to select provisioning file in XCode build settings under "code signing identity"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am not able to get my app loaded on my phone unless I set the bundle identifier in info.plist to the full app ID prefixed by the bundle seed ID "12345.com.app.name". When I put the correct bundle ID of "com.app.name" I get the dreaded error of "your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile."

What I think may be part of the issue: I noticed I'm getting strange behavior I haven't seen before... normally in the build settings under "code signing identity" you can see which certificates and provisioning profiles match up

[image]
However I'm not seeing that in my GUI, which just lists the certs without telling me which provisioning profile they match:

[image]

My provisioning profiles are definitely installed - they all show up in the organizer and I can in fact build for the device fine (but only when I set bundle ID to include the seed ID).

Anybody know why my screenshot doesn't include the provisioning profile matches? XCode does get confused sometimes, solvable by restart/reboot, but unfortunately this was not one of those cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provisioning profile's Application Identifiers stats 'uk.co.bailim', not com.app.name..

If you want to use com.app.name in bundle identifier, make sure that when you create your provisioning profile, put the com.app.name as Bundle ID as well..

Hope it helps.. =)

Comment: I'm pretty sure s/he was just using "com.app.name" as an example. At least, I hope s/he was.

Comment: heh yup, I was just filling in example numbers - 12345 would be an interesting Bundle Seed...

Comment: so in your info.plist, u put uk.co.bailim??